# Would like to use PubNub to send real-time updates to the user's web browser

Tags: python, django, heroku, real-time-updates, pubnub

Looking in to using PubNub to send real-time updates to the user's web browser.

I looked over their website and materials. It looks like they have a few different options.

We would like to use it for sending real time updates to a web page that a user is looking at. The information is simple stuff like "You just received a message". We are not trying ti implement a chat program or anything like that.

Is PubNub a good solution for this? If so, which version of the service should be be using?

We are running Django on a Heroku server.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm in the process of creating an easy start example for you now and will have it ready for you to use.  I have a quick question: are you looking for a notification like this: http://blog.pubnub.com/html5-mass-broadcasting-desktop-notifications/

Comment: @PubNub - That looks similar. It doesn't need to be a desktop notification though. It only needs to work inside the browser. It would be like if you were on a facebook and a notification lit up on the page letting you know you had a message. Nothing that should require extra permissions. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Chris, excellent.  We are working on an example today and will have some code and documentation on how this can be accomplished.

Comment: Hi Chris, we are still actively preparing an easy starting point for you.  We will provide a link and documentation today along with sample code and a working example.

Comment: https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-api/tree/master/app-showcase/facebook-notification - PubNub Facebook Notification Window Example - Next will be adding the Python Push support.

Comment: Try it Now: http://pubnub-demo.s3.amazonaws.com/facebook-notification/index.html

Download Source Code: https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-api/tree/master/app-showcase/facebook-notification 

Also see below for the brief walk-through.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## PubNub Facebook Notification

This is an example of a Facebook-like
Window Box that notifies your user with a custom message via PubNub.
You can send updates to your users on their Mobile Phone or Browser.
This will show your user a notification; any notification you.

Using PubNub allows Data Push via WebSockets, BOSH, Comet and other Mechanisms
to be used in your application providing you the ability to send data
**AT ANY TIME** directly to your users via **MASS BROADCAST** or
**INDIVIDUAL NOTIFICATIONS**.

### Start Here: Live Demo

> **Try it Now:**
>   http://pubnub-demo.s3.amazonaws.com/facebook-notification/index.html
>
> **Download Source Code:** 
>   https://github.com/pubnub/javascript/tree/master/examples/facebook-notification

Begin here for easy copy/paste of code.
It is very easy to get started and we recommend you start
with the example link above before you begin.

#### Setup Your Page

First include the **FBootstrap** resources in order to provide the 
look and feel of the notification window.
Add these Styles to your HTML file.

```
<link href=bootstrap.css rel=stylesheet>
<style type=text/css> body { padding-top: 60px; } </style>
```

#### Data Connection Code

Next you need to setup a PubNub Data Connection and then
add rules for what to do with the data once it is received.

```
   <script src="https://pubnub.s3.amazonaws.com/pubnub-3.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-modal/2.2.6/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>(function(){

    // PubNub (For Data Push to User)
    var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
        subscribe_key : 'demo',
        ssl           : false
    });

    // Setup New Data Push Connectoin via PubNub
    pubnub.subscribe({
        restore  : true,
        channel  : 'example-user-id-1234',
        callback : show_notification
    });

    // Setup Alert Window
    $('#new-alert').modal({ keyboard : true });

    // Show the Notification Window
    function show_notification(message) {
        $('#new-alert').modal('show');
    }

    // Simulate Notification
    $('#simulate-notification').bind( 'mousedown', function() {
        pubnub.publish({
            channel : 'example-user-id-1234',
            message : 'alert'
        });
        return false;
    } );

    })();</script>
```

#### Python Push Example

Next you will want to add this `python` code
to your **Django** or any other framework.
You can add this to the `message post` code in your app.
This will post a notification to your user.
This specific example will cause a notification to appear
inside the Facebook Notification page.

```
pip install pubnub
```

#### Python Source

```
## PubNub Setup
import pubnub from Pubnub
pubnub = Pubnub( 'demo', 'demo', None, False )

## Push Notice to 'example-user-id-1234'
info = pubnub.publish({
    'channel' : 'example-user-id-1234',
    'message' : { 'your-data' : 'any-data-here' }
})
print(info)
```

Comment: Pl see the below ans. & give us some solution on this. thanks.

Comment: Can I use it for django? Any examples? Can I make a service similar to Instagram using it? @PubNub

Comment: Django: **yes.**
Examples: follow the basic Python Source above.
Build Instagram: **yes.**

Answer (score 8):

For something a bit less generic, employing signals triggered by even an API served by Django and very strong channel security , check out https://github.com/sivang/django-pubnub (straight from the oven ;)).

Comment: Sivan, I just added a comment on your blog about the new ```import``` statement. ```import pubnub from Pubnub``` (noted the lowercase). Thanks for putting that tutorial together.

Answer (score 1):

I do this kind of thing with pubnub & socket.io ... the client side is then very easy to manage, thanks to multiplexing. My code looks like this :

```
var pubnub_setup = {
    channel       : 'xxx',
    publish_key   : 'xxx',
    subscribe_key : 'xxx'
};

var price_update = io.connect( 'http://pubsub.pubnub.com/price_update', pubnub_setup );
var table_update = io.connect( 'http://pubsub.pubnub.com/table_update', pubnub_setup );    

price_update.on( 'connect', function() {
          // do stuff here
} );
table_update.on( 'connect', function() {
          // do stuff here
} );
table_update.on( 'message', function(message) {
          // do stuff here
} );
```

PN with socket.io https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-api/tree/master/socket.io

mutliplexing with socket.io http://vimeo.com/34496366