# how to send notifications to multiple users at a time in django?

Tags: django

I am creating a rental website, where users can pay online. I want to inform users to pay the bills monthly once. how can I send the notification to all at once in django?

Comment: you could write a script, maybe in python, that does exactly that what you want...

Answer (score -1):

One example of setting up "poor man's notification system" would consist of creating a `UserNotifications` database table, containing the `userId` (fk), a `message`, a `createdate` and a `readdate` bit field.
When the user logs in or hits a page, simply get the unread messages for the user and display them in whatever way you like. You can fine-grain this to your needs with other tables and such. For a non-real-time use case, this might be sufficient.

If you need more real-time bells and whistles and/or want to offload the heavy lifting to an external messaging platform, there are many posts such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656117/would-like-to-use-pubnub-to-send-real-time-updates-to-the-users-web-browser) on here, that can help you on your way.